# Error when trying to typeset resistances in circuitkz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I get an error called `\ProcessOptions\relax`. I don't have any idea what could it be. I guess that maybe `spanish` `babel` gives problems.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\spanishdecimal{.}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[symbols]{circuitikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
 (0,0) node[anchor=east]{B}
  to[short, o-*] (1,0)
  to[R, l=$20\ohm$, *-*] (1,2)
  to [R, v=$v_x$, l=$10\ohm$] (3,2)
  to[short] (4,2) to[cI, i=$$, *-*] (4,0)
   to[short] (3,0) to[R, l=$5\ohm$, *-*] (3,2)
 (3,0) -- (1,0)
 (1,2) to[short, *-o] (0,2)
  node[anchor=east]{A}
;\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `symbols` doesn't appear to be an option for `circuitikz`

Comment: I'm sure it is not the right way but `\let\ohm\Omega` in the preamble gets it to compile. (And produces more-or-less sensible-looking output.)

Comment: I am a bit baffled.

The error using the intended syntax, that is `(0,0) to[R=20<\ohm>] (2,0)` appears using `babel` specifically with the `spanish` option. I'll look into it as soon as I have time.
Meanwhile, I'd advise to use the full syntax `to[R=\SI{20}{\ohm}]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error messages in (La)TeX can be cryptic, and even misleading, but this one is pretty explicit:

```
Unknown option `symbols' for package `circuitikz'
```

A quick look at the [`circuitikz` manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) (section 2: *Options*) will give you confirmation that the `circtuitkz` package indeed does not provide any option called `symbols`; at least, the latest version (0.3.0) does not.

To fix the problem with your labels, you need to load `circuitikz` with option `siunitx`:

> `siunitx`: integrates with `siunitx` package. If labels, currents or voltages are of the form `#1<#2>` then what is shown is actually `\SI{#1}{#2}`.

Those directions are a bit unclear, but what they mean is that you need to use `siunitx`'s `\SI` macro to typeset resistance labels (values and units). Here is an example:

```
\SI{20}{\ohm}
```

[image]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\spanishdecimal{.}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
 (0,0) node[anchor=east]{B}
  to[short, o-*] (1,0)
  to[R, l=\SI{20}{\ohm}, *-*] (1,2)
  to [R, v=$v_x$, l=\SI{10}{\ohm}] (3,2)
  to[short] (4,2) to[cI, i=, *-*] (4,0)
   to[short] (3,0) to[R, l=\SI{5}{\ohm}, *-*] (3,2)
 (3,0) -- (1,0)
 (1,2) to[short, *-o] (0,2)
  node[anchor=east]{A};
  \end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know why the syntax described in the package doesn't work? That is, if I load `circuitikz` with the `siunitx` option, and say e.g. `5<\ohm>` (I also tried `$5<\ohm>$`, I still get errors even though `circuitikz suggests this should work.

Comment: @cfr Perhaps the author made changes in the package that are not reflected in the documentation.

Comment: @cfr See my edit. I'm not 100% sure of what's going on; the documentation is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Thanks. Methinks there is something wrong with either the documentation or the code (of the package - not yours). The examples in the manual clearly show the `<>` syntax and yet it does not work whether or not the option for `siunitx` is given... +1 for giving code which *does* work *despite* the manual. (When I tried, I tried following the examples from the docs and just got errors.)